# Get class type when registering singleton with ServiceCollection?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class declare like,

```
ConsoleLogger : ILogger
```

It requires a type passed to the constructor.

```
public ConsoleLogger(Type classType)
```

So when changing this line to DI, it got a little difficult.

```
private readonly ILogger Logger = new ConsoleLogger(GetType());
```

If I want to register it to ServiceCollection, like so, is there a way to pass in the type?

```
sc.AddSingleton<ILogger, ConsoleLogger>(provider =>
    new ConsoleLogger(GetType()) // not GetType() but the type  you're injecting into.
)
```

So if I have a class with a constructor like this,

```
public SomeClass(ILogger logger){}
```

It should be something like this?

```
sc.AddSingleton<ILogger, ConsoleLogger>(provider =>
    new ConsoleLogger(typeof(SomeClass))
)
```

It would be good if I could get this to work dynamically, is it possible?

Comment: I think there's a few ways to solve this, each with their own benefit. 

You could have the signature of the class be explicit about implementation requirements. For example, `public SomeClass(ILogger<SomeClass> logger)`

You could also pass in a factory for the logger, such as `public SomeClass(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)`.

Comment: Option one doesn't fix anything, it isn't dynamic, and its what I could have done anyway. The second option feels promising, is there any chance you could show a code example of that idea?

Comment: That really depends on your logging method and DI choice. The documentation for how you would do this using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging is at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.iloggerfactory?view=aspnetcore-2.1